# Realtime Transfer Protocol (RTP) belongs to which layer of OSI?

Tags: voip

Real-time Transfer Protocol (RTP) belongs to which layer of OSI?

Various people said various things from transport-layer to application-layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTP is an Application Layer protocol, because at the Transport Layer, RTP implementations use either UDP or TCP (most commonly UDP).

Comment: @anonymous, I don't know why you are stuck on a maximum of 4 headers. There could be a maximum of 3 network headers on a frame: layer-2 frame, layer-3 packet, layer-4 segment.An application can use any of number of nested datagrams, which may use headers, above layer-4. As I have tried to tell you many times, this is completely dependent on the application. This is a networking forum, so, from that perspective, you might say that the maximum number of network headers is 3, but you can't make such a statement about the application datagrams/headers without discussing the specific application.